# Split a JSON string value using JMESPath

Tags: json, jmespath

I have a payload in a format similar to below:

```json
{
  "year": "2022", 
  "cycle": "Aug", 
  "origin": {
    "file_location": "GDT Post-Distribution Manifest/Italy/Rome/2022/Aug/Italy Rome_202208241528.xlsx", 
    "protocol": "s3:"
  }
}
```

I want to check if the third element of the `file_location` is equal to something (in this case it is marked as `Rome`).
How do I gain access this element?

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve this, you would need to have some sort of functionality to split a string, which is, sadly, not something that exists in the language for the moment being.

There is a proposal to add the functionality, though: [*New function: `array[string] split(string $separator, string $subject)`*](https://github.com/jmespath/jmespath.site/issues/35).