# select part of AWS CLI query output

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, jmespath

I want to return only the current AWS username using AWS CLI. I'm on Windows 11. I think there's a way to do it using a regex but I can't figure out how. I think I need to use a pipe along with a regex but there's no related examples on the [JMESPath website](https://jmespath.org/examples.html). I want to have something like "only return the text after 'user/' ".

Here's what I have so far:

`aws sts get-caller-identity --output text --query 'Arn'`

which returns `"arn:aws:iam::999999009999:user/joe.smith"

I just want to return `"joe.smith"`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74071913/split-a-json-string-value-using-jmespath

Comment: I've seen an example using a Linux cut command like this: `aws sts get-caller-identity --output text --query 'Arn' | cut -d\"/\" -f2`. Couldn't I do something using Powershell syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`jmes` does not support splitting a string nor matching a substring in a string, so you'll have to resort to a native command like:

```
> (aws sts get-caller-identity --output text --query 'Arn').Split("/")[-1]
```

or use something like `jq` :

```
$ aws sts get-caller-identity --output json | jq '.Arn | split("/")[-1]' -r
```

Comment: Thanks. The native command worked. Using `jq` didn't work.

Comment: @mdailey77 well, "didn't work" doesn't tell me much. What error do you see when using the `jq` solution?

Comment: This is the error I got:
`jq: The term 'jq' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.`

Comment: @mdailey77 that means `jq` isn't installed