Sorting Result of JMES Query based on IP Adddress
I have a JMESP query which returns me IP Addresses:
--query "[].{Zone: '$($zone.Name)', IPv4: aRecords[0].ipv4Address, Name: name}

From here
Now I want to sort the result based on the IP Address like this post
I tried this code:
[].{Zone: '$($zone.Name)', IPv4: aRecords[0].ipv4Address, Name: name} | sort_by(.IPv4 | split(".")[] | tonumber)

But it get the following error message:
az : ERROR: argument --query: expected one argument

So do you have any idea how can I do that?

JMESPath and jq are two different libraries, you cannot apply thing from one to the other.

And splitting a string is not something that is included in JMESPath for the moment, so what you want is not feasible. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74071913/split-a-json-string-value-using-jmespath
